# The property "Redirectstandarderror" on process startinfo used in reflection is not opening the console window

Tags: c#, reflection, redirectstandardoutput

I have a requirement to start a process using reflection.Below is the piece of code I'm trying to execute using reflection.

```
Process newProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo =new ProcessStartInfo(filepath);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow=false;
newProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
newProcess.Start();
newProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Compilation:(The parameter "codeToExecute" has the class structure with the above piece of code placed in a method)

```
private static CompilerResults CompileAndGetResult(SnippetInfo snippetInfo, string codeToExecute)
        {
            CompilerResults result = null;
            using (Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider foo =
             new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
                result = foo.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                  new CompilerParameters(snippetInfo.References.ToArray())
                  {
                      GenerateInMemory = true
                  },
                  codeToExecute
               );
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Execution Using Reflection:

```
var classType = result.CompiledAssembly.GetType(SnippetCodeGenerator.TypeName);
var classobj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(SnippetCodeGenerator.MethodName);
object returnValue = methodInfo.Invoke(classobj, parameterArray);
```

Using this code,my console is not getting opened.If I remove UseShellExecute and RedirectStandardError,I was able to see the console.I tried different ways using allocconsole as well.But nothing seems to be worked out.

Comment: There is no *reflection* here...

Comment: I'll create a dummy class structure,place the code in it and execute using reflection.Do you want me to share the code?

Comment: Does the code work as is? without reflection?

Comment: Please share the entire code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @thehennyy, Please find the edits.